# Change color of json file keywords or comments in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanted to customize the color of comments or keywords(not sure what they are called but I have described them in the picture attached.).So how can I change their color using "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" in vs code.(The code in red color has to be changed.)[image: PIC HERE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Scopes` Inspector from the Command Palette, click on those json keys and you will see their scope.  Which can be used like this in your `settings.json`:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "support.type.property-name.json.comments",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#00ff00",
          "fontStyle": "bold",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

If you want to restrict the above change to a particular color theme, use this form:

````
```jsonc
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai Classic]": {              // your theme name here
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": "support.type.property-name.json.comments",
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#00ff00",
            "fontStyle": "bold",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
````